# Any programming language which is faster to read a file than PHP's readfile(test.html); @ 20.000,- hits / second?

Tags: php, performance, file, webserver

What **Server Side Programming Language**, which without a single doubt is THE FASTEST to output a file content? (I am looking at ~20k file hits / second, so YES it does matter if certain X Language can output a file 1ms faster then PHP).

Because PHP was my language of choice, I have read the following links before I posted this question (but suddenly it raised a question, which server side programming language that is faster than PHP?)

http://raditha.com/wiki/Readfile_vs_include

When you state your answer, please also tell me the method that is used to read file. So dont just say FASTCGI/PHP, but also the method used to read the file, such as in this case `readfile();`

Comment: The fastest thing you can do is create a CGI (c++, c) that outputs the file

Comment: FASTCGI/C++ is faster than FASTCGI/PHP to output a file? can anyone confirm this? so you are saying FASTCGI/PHP's readfile(test.html); x 20k is slower than FASTCGI/C++'s cout<<output; x 20k ?

Comment: Any interpreted language has a virtual machine of sort that executes the code. With PHP it's ZendEngine, with Java it's the Java VM and so on - therefore, there's the overhead compared to a compiled binary. The fastest way to read a file is using a binary (written in C++/C) that gets executed as CGI. It **will not** be 20x faster than [insert language]. Period. It will be **slightly** faster, it will most likely scale better with more users using your app. There's also the server hardware setup issue too, it's not just the programming language that you have to consider.

Comment: Hmmm very interesting.. thanks a  lot for the information on fastcgi/C++, i will look into this.. can you also comment on fastcgi/perl ? shouldnt perl be faster than php for simple file reading?

Comment: I'm just going to repeat my statement before that your actual *app* shouldn't be seeing 20k hits per second on static files; that vast majority of those hits should really be handled by a reverse proxy cache written by the people who are experts at this stuff (e.g. nginx, squid). Your app code should only have to handle cache misses, which should be a far lower number (and for static-content, near-zero). Please, listen to someone who does this for a living on a site that almost certainly gets more traffic than yours does: you're focusing on the wrong problem.

Comment: sir, i am hosting my site in softlayer.com, and my server is behind a CDN layer, i know all about caching, so i have no problem with that at all.. This question is made For the sake of choosing the best programming language to output a static file. and that is all i want to do :) ... I know you are trying to be helpful here, and you are indeed :D .. But please stop talking about cache, i've already got it :D ... can you care to review on FASTCGI/PERL (do you have any experience with perl?)

Comment: It makes no sense to output a **static** file trough a programming language. None at all. Unless you have something like restricted download area, you shouldn't be using languages such as Perl/PHP (or even c++/c) to output static files.

Comment: @taufik chowi: I understand that you're trying to decide what language to use and you are no longer talking about the cache. What I'm trying to tell you is that once you're past the cache, the language you're using really *doesn't matter*. Your choice at that point shouldn't be about speed, it should be about what you (and/or any other developers who are working on the project) are most comfortable working with, because you will get a better result out of a slightly slower language that your programmers can create better code in, than a faster one that they create poorer code in.

Comment: @Amber, looks like you are right ... after much consideration on how much research i need to do to learn the new script again... I guess i will stick with php :) .. I dont have to worry about caching anymore (just a simple header expire will do the tricks), because there is another layer before my application (that is the CDN) .... But some part of my application will require a dynamic content (such as comment , etc), and my server has saved all latest comment on separate static files (so that when it is requested the script will simply read it)...

Comment: Instead of caching to static files, cache to Memcache if you really are desperate for performance and won't settle for less.

Comment: @N.B Memcache uses memory to store information right? , i am afraid i wont be going that way, because memory is a very very expensive resources (considering that i use a dedicated server from softlayer.com) :( ... Static File is the only possible way (fastest and cheapest too) .. the CDN layer has pretty much handle 90% of my application (the layout, design, page, js, css, image), the 10% that such as rating, comment, voting, forum must be handled by a simple static file cache (which will be read dynamically), well i care not about the seo of those dynamic content anyway :)) .. anyway thanks

Comment: I just mentioned what's the fastest. Memory is actually super-cheap compared to other resources, but I'm guessing your provider isn't as flexible as others are. Anyway, for unparalleled performance - storing info on fast memory store is definitely the fastest. Just remember it for future reference.

Comment: @taufik if you only cache the most recent comments (say, the most recent 100,000 comments), which are the ones people are likely to be actually viewing, it will not take much memory to put them in memcache - and you will still get memcache-level performance, because the older comments probably aren't being read frequently. (If say your average comment is 1Kb, then 100,000 of those is only 100Mb of memory, a very trivial amount to add to a machine.)

Comment: Also note that you might still want to run `nginx` as a reverse proxy for your dynamic content even if you're using a CDN - `nginx` will essentially give you on-disk caching for free without you having to write it yourself, since that's how reverse proxying works (and it'll even automatically cache the most popular stuff in memory for an even better speedup). Sure, that dynamic content might change once a minute if someone adds a new comment every minute, but you can set a much lower expiry interval for nginx and still get improved performance from its caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (I am looking at ~20k file hits / second , that is why i have totally abandoned the idea to use apache at all, and i really dont want my poor choice of Server Side Programming Language actually slow down the file output , so YES it does matter if certain X Language can output a file 1ms faster then PHP )

The thing is, are all of those 20k hits/second going to be requiring generation of the file? That seems unlikely. After the first generation of a static file, you can just configure `nginx` to cache it, so all of the requests after that will hit the cached version and never invoke your server-side language at all.

> I also need a server side script to check if this file existed or not

*That's the point of having a proxy cache like `nginx` there in the first place.*

So are you sure you're really chasing the right problem here? The numbers you should be giving us are not how many *hits* you expect per second, but rather how many *cache misses* you expect per second. After all, if you're serving, say, 600 files that change once every minute, that's only going to be on the order of 10 cache misses per second, which is a much more manageable number for the actual server-side program to handle (and makes the choice of language less of an issue).

So, do tell us more: what's your cache hit/miss rate going to be like? A 10% cache miss rate is a lot different than a 1% cache miss rate, and so on.

Comment: +1: Or just stick with Apache and PHP and put a (nginx/Varnish?) reverse proxy in front of it. Although I'm having a lot trouble understanding the scenario where you'd be handling this volume of traffic on a single server in the first place.

Comment: @symcbean: from the OP, it seems like they're already wanting to use nginx which can handle the reverse proxying just fine, so that's why my entire point is "what is the real problem here?"

Comment: The Content generation should not be a problem, because it will only generate once, and everytime when a content is changed or updated the server "SHOULD" have generate a new static file even before it was hit. Anyway my point is simple , ignoring the x-sendfile header or any proxy or any other web server capability, "is there any language that can perform faster then PHP's readfile(test.html); x 20k" for NGINX ? .. @N.B mentioned that CGI would be able to output a static file faster than PHP, is it true?

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that you is that `nginx` already handles the "outputting a static file" part for you if you set it up correctly; it's not going to be calling PHP for anything but the first request. If you tell it to, `nginx` will cache the static file itself and use its own methods to read it off disk, thus being faster than anything else because it requires NO language.

Comment: somehow i regretted mentioning nginx at all :( . okay forgetting that i would even use nginx at the first place, is there any programming language that can perform file reading faster than PHP's readfile(test.html); x 20k ?

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language, so there's a small overhead due to the interpreter. A native-compiled application (in other words, a CGI program) written in something that can compile to machine code, like C/C++, would most likely slightly outperform `readfile()` - but only marginally, and the margin would likely go down as the files got larger. (But just to reiterate - there's no reason why anything *you* write should *have* to read something 20k times a second. That's what caches are for; use them.)

Comment: But a webserver can not talk with C/C++ directly right? they also need CGI (or better yet FASTCGI) , wont that incur the same small overhead?

Comment: @taufik chowi - PHP's readfile can be replaced with chunked output (fopen / fread / echo combination with 2kb chunks) that's already about 60% faster than readfile. Also, there are Direct IO functions that I haven't used that might also provide better performance.

Comment: i was wondering if FASTCGI/PERL is faster or not compared to FASTCGI/PHP ?

Comment: @N.B wait a second, you are saying fopen->fread is faster than readfile() ?? are you serious? , 20k x fopen->fread should blow away my memory (if i am not mistaken)??

Comment: @taufik chowi - with PHP, the process looks like "nginx - interface - PHP interpreter - PHP code", versus "nginx - interface - compiled C/C++ code". `nginx` can't talk directly to PHP either - the interface overhead will always be there. The point is that PHP has an *additional* layer of the interpreter, because it does not compile to native machine code.

Comment: You're mistaken. readfile is a slow function, it works faster when you have relatively small file and a few users on your site therefore it eludes you into thinking it's more effective when in reality it's really slow and leaves larger memory footprint. I said chunked output, it means you read 2kbs at a time and output them - it's readfile that would blow away your memory.

Comment: Also regarding chunked reads - `readfile()` uses `fopen` and `fread` internally, @taufik, so the memory usage will be the same. What N.B. is referring to is the fact that PHP's `readfile()` could be smarter in how it works - see the comments about "readfile_chunked" on the `readfile()` php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: @N.B have you read this ? http://raditha.com/wiki/Readfile_vs_include , is this guys research all wrong? O.o;

Comment: @taufik chowi - functions compared at the link provided aren't doing the same thing, it's like comparing rollerblades and a car in terms of speed. It's what Amber mentioned - the readfile function isn't optimal enough for uses such as yours and yes, you can get more out of PHP by creating your own function that uses available resources more effectively.

Comment: @N.B hmmm interesting assessment, give me 15 minutes, let me try it myself :D , in the meantime can you comment on FASTCGI/PERL?? Oh by the way when you were talking about Direct IO, are you talking about dio_read() ? i will test it now too and report here with my finding

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about dio_* functions. As of FastCGI + Perl - I've no work experience with Perl itself so my comment might be misleading.